# How to format a java String as JSP code and save it to file?

Tags: java

I have a Java string containing JSP code which I generated programmatically. I want the code in the string to be properly formatted and aligned and then save the code on disk.

I am already formatting some strings as Java code using Formatter.formatSource() method and even XML code in string can be formatted using javax.xml.transform.Transformer.

But I could not find anything similar to properly format the string as JSP code.

Comment: In a servlet's doGet one can set a request attribute Sing value using some attribute name. Then in the servlet using the requestDispatcher forward to a JSP that takes the request attribute. _Is that what you mean?_

Comment: No Eggen, I have JSP code in a Java string. I want to print that string on console so that the whole code is not in a single line but aligned properly. I want to format the code in string programmatically just like we format the code manually in eclipse editor using ctrl+shift+F.

Comment: You have to format the code yourself. `"<%\n\tif (c) {\n\t\t++i;\n\t\tf();\n\t}\n%>\n"`. Of course the JSP is not compiled.

Answer (score 0):

it likes html.

**so try this:**

```
  Spanned spannedContent = Html.fromHtml(YOUR_STRING);
    textView.setText(spannedContent, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

Comment: I think that's Android specific. I am using eclipse and Java 8. I want to print the properly formatted JSP code(and not render it).